# IO With Callback to set Database status

Tags: java, hibernate, optimization

Give this

```
public void do(RequestObject request, Callback<RequestObject> callback);
```

Where `Callback` is called when the request is processed. One client has to set status of the request to the database. The client fetches some items passes them to the above method and the callback sets the status.

It was working ok for small number of items and slower IO. But now, the IO is speed up and the status is written to database vary frequently. This is causing my database (MySQL) to make so many disk read write calls. My disk usage goes through the roof.

I was thinking of aggregating the setting of status but power in not reliable, that is not a plausible solution. How should re'design this?

**EDIT**

When the process is started I insert a value and when there is an update, I fetch the item and update the item. @user2612030 Your question lead me to believe, using hibernate might be what is causing more reads than it is necessary.

I can upgrade my disk drive to SSD but that would only do so much. I want a solution that scales.

Comment: What are the use-cases for the status after it has been stored? How soon do you need to query it?

Comment: I query it to check the status of the operation. It is a bulk operation and clients need to check the status.

Comment: Can change of the status value be eventually consistent then? I mean can it be approached like that - client sets the status, but it is not saved immediately to the database, but rather to some fast durable storage like a persistent on-disk queue. You can cache and serve the status in/from memory while instance is running  meanwhile bulk updating the database in the background from the queue. Upon restart you'd have to sync the database and the cache by replaying events from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SSD is a good starting point, more RAM to MySQL should also help. It can't get rid of the writes, but with enough RAM (and MySQL configured to use it!) there should be few physical reads. If you are using the default configuration, tune it. See for example https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/12/mysql-5-7-performance-tuning-immediately-after-installation/ or just search for MySQL memory configuration.

You could also add disks and spread the writes to multiple disks with multiple controllers. That should also help a bit.

It is hard to give good advice without knowing how you record status values. Inserts or updates? How many records are there? Data model? However, to really scale you need to shard the data somehow. That way one server can handle data in one range and another server data in another range and so on.

For write-heavy applications that is non-trivial to set up with MySQL unless you do the sharding in the application code. Most solutions with replication work best for read-mostly applications. You may want to look into a NoSQL database, for example MongoDB, that has been designed for distributing writes from the outset. MongoDB has other challenges (eventual consistency), but it can deliver scalable writes.